# add_weight() got multiple values for argument 'name' while using a custom Attention(Layer) in Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

(I think this is because of the version conflict as the authors have used `keras.engine.topology.Layer`)

**With tensorflow==2.2.0 and keras==2.4.3**, I am trying to learn the Attention Mechanism and have imported the code from somewhere as:

```
from keras import backend as K
from keras.engine.topology import Layer
from keras import initializers, regularizers, constraints

from keras.layers import Dense, Input, LSTM, Bidirectional, Activation, Conv1D, GRU, TimeDistributed
from keras.layers import Dropout, Embedding, GlobalMaxPooling1D, MaxPooling1D, Add, Flatten, SpatialDropout1D
from keras.layers import GlobalAveragePooling1D, BatchNormalization, concatenate
from keras.layers import Reshape, merge, Concatenate, Lambda, Average
from keras.models import Sequential, Model
from keras.initializers import Constant
from keras.layers.merge import add


class Attention(Layer):
    def __init__(self, step_dim,
                 W_regularizer=None, b_regularizer=None,
                 W_constraint=None, b_constraint=None,
                 bias=True, **kwargs):
        self.supports_masking = True
        self.init = initializers.get('glorot_uniform')
        self.W_regularizer = regularizers.get(W_regularizer)
        self.b_regularizer = regularizers.get(b_regularizer)
        self.W_constraint = constraints.get(W_constraint)
        self.b_constraint = constraints.get(b_constraint)
        self.bias = bias
        self.step_dim = step_dim
        self.features_dim = 0
        super(Attention, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def build(self, input_shape):
        assert len(input_shape) == 3
        self.W = self.add_weight((input_shape[-1],),
                                 initializer=self.init,
                                 name='{}_W'.format(self.name),
                                 regularizer=self.W_regularizer,
                                 constraint=self.W_constraint)
        self.features_dim = input_shape[-1]
        if self.bias:
            self.b = self.add_weight((input_shape[1],),
                                     initializer='zero',
                                     name='{}_b'.format(self.name),
                                     regularizer=self.b_regularizer,
                                     constraint=self.b_constraint)
        else:
            self.b = None
        self.built = True

    def compute_mask(self, input, input_mask=None):
        return None

    def call(self, x, mask=None):
        features_dim = self.features_dim
        step_dim = self.step_dim
        eij = K.reshape(K.dot(K.reshape(x, (-1, features_dim)), K.reshape(self.W, (features_dim, 1))), (-1, step_dim))
        if self.bias:
            eij += self.b
        eij = K.tanh(eij)
        a = K.exp(eij)
        if mask is not None:
            a *= K.cast(mask, K.floatx())
        a /= K.cast(K.sum(a, axis=1, keepdims=True) + K.epsilon(), K.floatx())
        a = K.expand_dims(a)
        weighted_input = x * a
        return K.sum(weighted_input, axis=1)

    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        return input_shape[0],  self.features_dim
```

The Problem is when I try to use,

```
lstm_layer = LSTM(300, dropout=0.25, recurrent_dropout=0.25, return_sequences=True)

inp = Input(shape=(maxlen,), dtype='int32')
embedding= embedding_layer(inp)
x = lstm_layer(embedding)
x = Dropout(0.25)(x)
merged = Attention(maxlen)(x)
merged = Dense(256, activation='relu')(merged)
merged = Dropout(0.25)(merged)
merged = BatchNormalization()(merged)
outp = Dense(len(int_category), activation='softmax')(merged)

AttentionLSTM = Model(inputs=inp, outputs=outp)
AttentionLSTM.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['acc'])

AttentionLSTM.summary()
```

it throws an error as **TypeError: add_weight() got multiple values for argument 'name'**

Full traceback of the error is:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-25-1ab1f1ef1ed7> in <module>
      5 x = lstm_layer(embedding)
      6 x = Dropout(0.25)(x)
----> 7 merged = Attention(maxlen)(x)
      8 merged = Dense(256, activation='relu')(merged)
      9 merged = Dropout(0.25)(merged)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    895           # Build layer if applicable (if the `build` method has been
    896           # overridden).
--> 897           self._maybe_build(inputs)
    898           cast_inputs = self._maybe_cast_inputs(inputs)
    899 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py in _maybe_build(self, inputs)
   2414         # operations.
   2415         with tf_utils.maybe_init_scope(self):
-> 2416           self.build(input_shapes)  # pylint:disable=not-callable
   2417       # We must set also ensure that the layer is marked as built, and the build
   2418       # shape is stored since user defined build functions may not be calling

<ipython-input-20-86a01469b2e5> in build(self, input_shape)
     23                                  name='{}_W'.format(self.name),
     24                                  regularizer=self.W_regularizer,
---> 25                                  constraint=self.W_constraint)
     26         self.features_dim = input_shape[-1]
     27         if self.bias:

TypeError: add_weight() got multiple values for argument 'name'
```

Comment: I have the same Issue on TF version 2.2.0 and Keras 2.3.1

Comment: Did you find any solution to solve this problem?

Comment: I am facing the same issue now.

Answer (score 5):

The issue is coming because the add_weight function is taking value from the shape tuples.
Try writing "**shape** = shape(YOUR INPUT)" . This should resolve the issue.

Comment: Hello Jayesh, this is not a very helpful piece of information. Could you please report the code above with the appropriate modules imported and the "shape=shape(input)" correctly placed in your version? That would help us much more. Welcome to the community.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion but I think you have already looked into that issue and answered it perfectly.

Comment: Yeah Jayesh, I have actually used part of your answer. :)

Answer (score 3):

I have partially resolved the issue. At least for the add_weight() part:

- Step 1: Replace class Attention(Layer) -> class Attention(keras.layers.Layer)
- Step 2: Add shape=(...) inside of the add_weights methods

See below,

```
from keras import backend as K
from keras.engine.topology import Layer
from keras import initializers, regularizers, constraints

from keras.layers import Dense, Input, LSTM, Bidirectional, Activation, Conv1D, GRU, TimeDistributed
from keras.layers import Dropout, Embedding, GlobalMaxPooling1D, MaxPooling1D, Add, Flatten, SpatialDropout1D
from keras.layers import GlobalAveragePooling1D, BatchNormalization, concatenate
from keras.layers import Reshape, merge, Concatenate, Lambda, Average
from keras.models import Sequential, Model
from keras.initializers import Constant
from keras.layers.merge import add


class Attention(keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, step_dim,
                 W_regularizer=None, b_regularizer=None,
                 W_constraint=None, b_constraint=None,
                 bias=True, **kwargs):
        self.supports_masking = True
        self.init = initializers.get('glorot_uniform')
        self.W_regularizer = regularizers.get(W_regularizer)
        self.b_regularizer = regularizers.get(b_regularizer)
        self.W_constraint = constraints.get(W_constraint)
        self.b_constraint = constraints.get(b_constraint)
        self.bias = bias
        self.step_dim = step_dim
        self.features_dim = 0
        super(Attention, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def build(self, input_shape):
        assert len(input_shape) == 3
        self.W = self.add_weight(shape=(input_shape[-1],),
                                 name='{}_W'.format(self.name),
                                 initializer=self.init,
                                 regularizer=self.W_regularizer,
                                 constraint=self.W_constraint)
        self.features_dim = input_shape[-1]
        if self.bias:
            self.b = self.add_weight((input_shape[1],),
                                     name='{}_b'.format(self.name),
                                     initializer='zero',
                                     regularizer=self.b_regularizer,
                                     constraint=self.b_constraint)
        else:
            self.b = None
        self.built = True

    def compute_mask(self, input, input_mask=None):
        return None

    def call(self, x, mask=None):
        features_dim = self.features_dim
        step_dim = self.step_dim
        eij = K.reshape(K.dot(K.reshape(x, (-1, features_dim)), K.reshape(self.W, (features_dim, 1))), (-1, step_dim))
        if self.bias:
            eij += self.b
        eij = K.tanh(eij)
        a = K.exp(eij)
        if mask is not None:
            a *= K.cast(mask, K.floatx())
        a /= K.cast(K.sum(a, axis=1, keepdims=True) + K.epsilon(), K.floatx())
        a = K.expand_dims(a)
        weighted_input = x * a
        return K.sum(weighted_input, axis=1)

    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        return input_shape[0],  self.features_dim
```

Making the changes above, I get the following outputs:

- I get a Warning from Tensorflow 
  `` "WARNING:tensorflow:Model failed to serialize as JSON. Ignoring... Layer AttentionWithContext has arguments in `__init__` and therefore must override `get_config`". ``
- When I try to evaluate the algorithm on test dataset I get the following error:

[image]

I don't know how to resolve those two issues, so I will probably post a different question because it's out of the scope of this one.

Comment: I think this is due to version conflict. Please share once you find out. I tried doing and failed because due to version change, workflow has changed.

Comment: @Deshwal you mean about the last error? of the test function?

Comment: When you change the structure like you have done, it'll throw some new error every now and then because of the changed workflow of 1.15 to 2.0

Answer (score 1):

The add_weights method is called three times in the code, try to fix it with 'shape ='.

Answer (score 0):

I had a same problem and then changed my environment. my venv as follow:

```
absl-py==0.11.0
astor==0.8.1
cached-property==1.5.2
certifi==2020.6.20
click==7.1.2
cycler==0.10.0
gast==0.4.0
google-pasta==0.2.0
grpcio==1.33.2
h5py==3.0.0
importlib-metadata==2.0.0
joblib==0.17.0
Keras==2.2.4
Keras-Applications==1.0.8
Keras-Preprocessing==1.1.2
kiwisolver==1.3.1
Markdown==3.3.3
matplotlib==3.3.2
nltk==3.5
numpy==1.18.1
pandas==0.25.3
Pillow==8.0.1
protobuf==3.13.0
pyparsing==2.4.7
python-dateutil==2.8.1
pytz==2020.4
PyYAML==5.3.1
regex==2020.10.28
scikit-learn==0.23.2
scipy==1.5.4
six==1.15.0
sklearn==0.0
tensorboard==1.14.0
tensorflow==1.14.0
tensorflow-estimator==1.14.0
termcolor==1.1.0
threadpoolctl==2.1.0
tqdm==4.51.0
Werkzeug==1.0.1
wrapt==1.12.1
zipp==3.4.0
```

Comment: Does it work properly with this environment setup?

Answer (score 0):

Add an explicit `shape=(input_shape[-1],)` call inside `add_weights`.

Here is the corrected version of the function:

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Layer
from keras import backend as K
from tensorflow import keras


class AttentionLayer(Layer):
    
    def __init__(self, step_dim,
                 W_regularizer=None, b_regularizer=None,
                 W_constraint=None, b_constraint=None,
                 bias=True, **kwargs):
        
        """
        Keras Layer that implements an Attention mechanism for temporal data.
        Supports Masking.
        Follows the work of Raffel et al. [https://arxiv.org/abs/1512.08756]
        # Input shape
            3D tensor with shape: `(samples, steps, features)`.
        # Output shape
            2D tensor with shape: `(samples, features)`.
        :param kwargs:
        Just put it on top of an RNN Layer (GRU/LSTM/SimpleRNN) with return_sequences=True.
        The dimensions are inferred based on the output shape of the RNN.
        """
        
        self.supports_masking = True
        self.init = keras.initializers.get('glorot_uniform')

        self.W_regularizer = keras.regularizers.get(W_regularizer)
        self.b_regularizer = keras.regularizers.get(b_regularizer)

        self.W_constraint = keras.constraints.get(W_constraint)
        self.b_constraint = keras.constraints.get(b_constraint)

        self.bias = bias
        self.step_dim = step_dim
        self.features_dim = 0
        super(AttentionLayer, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        

    def build(self, input_shape):
        assert len(input_shape) == 3

        self.W = self.add_weight(shape=(input_shape[-1],),
                                 initializer=self.init,
                                 name='{}_W'.format(self.name),
                                 regularizer=self.W_regularizer,
                                 constraint=self.W_constraint)
        self.features_dim = input_shape[-1]

        if self.bias:
            self.b = self.add_weight(shape=(input_shape[1],),
                                     initializer='zero',
                                     name='{}_b'.format(self.name),
                                     regularizer=self.b_regularizer,
                                     constraint=self.b_constraint)
        else:
            self.b = None

        self.built = True
        

    def compute_mask(self, input, input_mask=None):
        # do not pass the mask to the next layers
        return None

    
    def call(self, x, mask=None):
        # TF backend doesn't support it
        # eij = K.dot(x, self.W) 
        # features_dim = self.W.shape[0]
        # step_dim = x._keras_shape[1]

        features_dim = self.features_dim
        step_dim = self.step_dim

        eij = K.reshape(K.dot(K.reshape(x, (-1, features_dim)), 
                              K.reshape(self.W, (features_dim, 1))),
                        (-1, step_dim))

        if self.bias:
            eij += self.b

        eij = K.tanh(eij)

        a = K.exp(eij)

        # apply mask after the exp. will be re-normalized next
        if mask is not None:
            # Cast the mask to floatX to avoid float64 upcasting in theano
            a *= K.cast(mask, K.floatx())

        # in some cases especially in the early stages of training the sum may be almost zero
        a /= K.cast(K.sum(a, axis=1, keepdims=True) + K.epsilon(), K.floatx())
        a = K.expand_dims(a)
        weighted_input = x * a
        
        return K.sum(weighted_input, axis=1)

    
    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        return input_shape[0],  self.features_dim
    
    
    def get_config(self):
        config = {'step_dim': self.step_dim}
        base_config = super(AttentionLayer, self).get_config()
        return dict(list(base_config.items()) + list(config.items()))
```

Answer (score -1):

**Solution #1:**
For me it perfectly works with 
keras.version__ == 2.2.4 and tensorflow.__version == 1.15.2 
**Solution #2:** replace (input_shape[-1],) with shape=(input_shape[-1],) in all the self.add_weight() function. 
If you get any error like `get_config`. try without saving your model and try to save the weights instead. 
maybe you can use save_weights_only=True, for example use; 
 checkpointer = ModelCheckpoint(filepath='model_path.h5', verbose=1, save_best_only=True, save_weights_only=True)